# <ion-select> - How can I do some action whenever the select dialog is closed

Tags: ionic-framework

I have three options in my ion-select to indicate the packing of items by a seller,
The options are 'OPEN', 'PACKED', 'NOT AVL'.
I want to prompt the user to input the number of packed items whenever the selection is 'PACKED' by the time the selection dialog is closed. If I capture the event ionChange, it only triggers when the selection is changed. I want to trigger this even when he opens the selection dialog and closes it without changing the current selection. For this I need to capture the closure event of the selection dialog. How can I do this.

```
<ion-select      
      (ionChange)="onOrderElementStatusChanged(orderElement)"
      [(ngModel)]="orderElement.STATUS"
>
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let status of orderElementStatus"
         [value]="status">{{status}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

When I use ionBlur the callback is getting called twice for each selection
the code in that case is as below

```
<ion-select      
      (ionBlur)="onOrderElementStatusChanged(orderElement)"
      [(ngModel)]="orderElement.STATUS"
>
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let status of orderElementStatus"
         [value]="status">{{status}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs of the ion-select : https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#events, you can use the `(ionBlur)` event.

I updated your code :

```
<ion-select
      (ionBlur)="onBlur()"
      (ionChange)="onOrderElementStatusChanged(orderElement)"
      [(ngModel)]="orderElement.STATUS"
>
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let status of orderElementStatus"
         [value]="status">{{status}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: Thanks. But if you do not change your current selection neither one is getting called.

Comment: @3mr see my edited answer. I misunderstood your question. The ionBlur event is triggered when the user loses focus on the ion-select component

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this. But it gets triggered twice in a row when you click

Comment: Can you share your updated code please ? Because this should not be triggered twice

Comment: Thanks. Please see the updated code on the original question